# Combining levels from 3 to 1 (basic)

Tags: vector, merge

I have a data column called "Health" with the following four levels: "0 0", "0 1", "1 0" and "1 1"

How do I create a new column where I:

- combine the three levels "0 1", "1 0" and "1 1" and rename it as "1"
- rename the fourth level "0 0" as "0"

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific with which languages and/or frameworks you're concerned with?

Comment: Apologies, language is R version 3.6.2and framework is R studio.